# Evento de recarga callback en javascript ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

estoy trabajando con un select encadenado a otro. Al momento de crear el formulario funciona perfecto. Pero cuando voy a editar. El mismo no me carga los datos y debo de forma manual seleccionar otra opción y después volver a seleccionar la opción deseada.

Entiendo que me falta aplicar un reload pero estoy muy verde con este tipo de funciones. A lo mejor alguien me puede orientar.

Al editar el select padre carga el dato correspondiente, pero el select encadenado que lo manejo con javascript no muestra la relación además no permite la selección sin cambiar la categoría primero. Ahí se ve que hace un reload y posteriormente aparecen las opciones encadenadas en el segundo select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilizo sé que es Ecmascript 6.

```
$("#category_id").change(event => {
        $.get(`../getSubCategories/${event.target.value}`, function(response, state){
            $("#subcategory").empty();
            response.forEach(element => {
                $("#subcategory").append(`<option value=${element.id}> ${element.name} </option>`);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: bueno si el primero tambien carga de forma dinamica no estas seleccionandolo, debes hacer utilizar delegate ejemplo `("div#padreEstatico").on("change","#category_id",event => {` con esto seleccionas al padre del elemento que sea estatico para que jquery ree lea el documento a partir del padre y vea que elementos se an actualizado dentro del mismo y pueda ver a `#category_id` y su  nuevos elementos [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Entiendo lo que me indicas, lo agregué y no me trae la información. En esta parte a quien te refieres con el padre ("div#padreEstatico")? En mi código el padre es category_id y el hijo o el otro select anidado es subcategory.

Comment: Es el padre del elemento dinamico osea el que englobe a  `#category_id` no se cual sea en tu caso! es un ejemplo, puedes ver el ejemplo de la web de jquery